# Blazor capture events inside a ChildContent

Tags: event-handling, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm working in a component witch have a ChildContent list, this is an example:

```
    @foreach (var item in Items.Select((v, i) => (v, i)))
    {
        <div @ref="itemElem[item.i]" @onmousedown="async (e) => await onPress(e, item, itemElem[item.i])">
            @ChildContent(item.v)
        </div>
    }
```

Ok that works perfect, it renders the list without problem, and if I click on one item I can capture the event.

Now what I want to do is to detect the mousedown event in a handler inside the ChildContent, this is an example:

```
<MyComponent Items="list" TItem="ListItem" Handler="handler">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="handler col-auto">
            <i class="oi oi-grid-three-up"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h5>@context.title</h5>
            <p>@context.details</p>      
        </div>
    </div>
</MyComponent>
```

So, the idea is the parameter "Handler" tells me witch html tag (looking thought the class) accepts the event mousedown.

I need to accept the mouse down if the user clicked over the handler

I'm a little lost how to handle this, any idea?

**Edit:**

Maybe the question is: It is possible to fire @onmousedown from one html tag inside a ChildContent? Or, if it's no possible, exists a workaround for doing this?

Comment: So how do the first and second blocks of code fit together?  What is `Items` in the first block?  What does `OnPress` do?

Comment: The only advice I would give here is don't use a CSS class on a non-interactive element (div) to handle clicks. HTML has anchor tags for navigation and buttons for actions. What you are proposing is not accessible.

Comment: Thanks @MisterMagoo I understand what you said , but it's not a navigation neither an action (i think), is a drag functionality, you can see the complete project  here https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorReorder, I'll update the question to clarify

Comment: if this is your code, i.e. not a library, then I would pass the handler into the ChildContent renderfragment as a parameter and then it can be used in the markup directly against the correct element